# Check if browser notifications are temporary disabled in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, notifications, cross-browser

The permission of browser notifications can be checked with the `Notification.permission` property.

In firefox the user has the possibility to disabled the browser notifications temporary. This means the browser will ask for the permission to show notifications again when a new tab or window is opened.

When the user denied the permission temporary and I check the `Notification.permission` property it returns `default`.

When I run the following script I get `browser notifications where allowed` as output in the console.

```
Notification.requestPermission().then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

But then when I try to show notifications nothing happens (because they are temporary disabled).

---

> How can I check if browser notifications has been temporary disabled in firefox?

I could use the following script but it's an ugly workaround and it will trigger the dialog where the browser ask for permission. Can I do something else?

```
var calculateBrowserNotificationPermission = () => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var permission = Notification.permission;
        if(permission !== 'default') {
            resolve(permission);
            return;
        }

        Notification.requestPermission().then((result) => {
            if(result === 'default') {
                resolve('temporary_denied');       
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

---

Where would the best place be to ask for such a feature if it doesn't exist yet?

**EDIT 1**: I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/whatwg/notifications/issues/129) on the notification repository of `WHATWG`.

**EDIT 2**: I've closed the github issue and will persist if I've allready asked the user for permissions as suggested by @jib.

Comment: According to this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/permission 
the temporary disabled should return default and it should be handled as a denied. If this is not the case then I don't really see an other option to implement a workaround of 'if' loops to check whether it's default or not.

Comment: @mrdeadsven Thanks for your commend but I find the statement a little confusing. Why is there a state `default` when it should be handled the same as the `denied` state. How can I inform the user what his next steps should be when I do not know his state in greated detail. This just calls for ugly websites and long explanations so the user can work with this feature without beeing a poweruser.

Comment: Did you read whats on the site that I send to you? It clearly states: 'default: The user decision is unknown; in this case the application will act as if permission was denied.'. Default is used when the decision of the user is not known. This either is when they just close the notification or when they disable it temporary. You should not ask me why the method 'Notification.permission' works this way, Clearly somebody coded it to be this way for a reason but as for a why, I cannot provide you that answer as for I have not made this method.

Comment: I'm sorry if I somehow offended you but my goal is to check if the notifications are temporary disabled. And for this purpose I will ask any question nessesary. And if a new feature will be added some years down the road this is also great. I want to improve the way it works and not just settle.

Comment: I'm not offended I was just asking since you asked a question that was clearly stated in the article. If you want to check if it's temporary disabled I see no other way then something like this: if(Notification.permission === "default"){
//insert code that you wanne execute here
}
Sorry I don't see another solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But then when I try to show notifications nothing happens

You're using the API wrong. [requestPermission](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/requestPermission) doesn't reject on denied, it resolves with the result:

```
(async () => {
  try {
    console.log(await Notification.requestPermission()); // denied
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e); // never gets here
  }
})();
```

Any result other than `granted` here means you didn't get permission. Try it [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/6jdxz34x/).

- `granted` means you got persistent permission to do notifications.
- `denied` means the user chose to persistently block you.
- `default` means the user chose to not allow this time (initiating a temporary block in Firefox).

> How can I check if browser notifications has been temporary disabled in firefox?

Temporary blocks only happen in Firefox if you ask the user twice and they've already said "no" once in the same session. The user doing a page refresh ↻ should remove the block. Firefox is shielding the user from pestering web-sites at this point.

If you haven't already asked them, `default` means the user will be be prompted. Figuring out whether you already have, is hopefully easy, and if you have, don't bother them again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated my question so it uses the api correctly. It shouldn't have made any difference. I'll just persist that I've already asked the user in this session as suggested.